# What, if any, URL protocols should I whitelist or blacklist when spawning the user's browser?

Tags: url

I'm writing an app using Electron but I'd assume this would be a problem for any software that lets you open links in the user's default browser through the OS.

Let's say I have app that reads something *like* a twitter feed and displays it. So the app displays 10 entries. Some of those entries have user supplied links. If the user clicks a link I want to launch it in the user's default browser.

In Electron I'm told I should call `electron.shell.openExternal(url)`. Do I need to be filtering URLs? Common URLs are for example `http://xxx`, `https://xxx`, `mailto:xxx` so I could just whitelist those 3 types of URLs. At the same time I don't want to wrongly limit good functionality. In other words I have no idea what other valid schemas there are. Allow `ftp://`? `sftp://`? `gopher://`? So I'd prefer to just pass everything through.

At the same time I'm worried, are there are potentially bad URLs? Hypothetical example: `3rdpartyAppWithScriptingHandler://evil.script`

Should I whitelist? Blacklist? Filter? If so what's the filter? Or should I just pass them to OS?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I whitelist? Blacklist? Filter? If so what's the filter? Or should I just pass them to OS?

**You should whitelist.** I would go for a sensible minimum of `http:`, `https:`, `mailto:` and optionally `ftp:`. Including more protocols is unnecessary if you don't have a special use case in mind. That said some systems are more permissive than others. The [Wordpress docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_allowed_protocols/) define this list of safe protocols in their `wp_allowed_protocols()` function:

> Array of allowed protocols. Defaults to an array containing 'http',
>   'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'mailto', 'news', 'irc', 'gopher', 'nntp',
>   'feed', 'telnet', 'mms', 'rtsp', 'svn', 'tel', 'fax', 'xmpp', and
>   'webcal'.

None of these are *inherently* unsafe but you will not have any use case for a `fax:` or `gopher:` URL.

> At the same time I'm worried, are there are potentially bad URLs?

There are pseudo-protocols that have side effects. `javascript:` URLs should definitely not be possible. The `file:` scheme is dangerous as well because local files are often more privileged than web content. For Firefox you especially don't want to allow `chrome:` and `resource:` URIs.

This is a good example for a problem where only whitelisting works since it's not possible to keep track of all the custom URI schemes and their effects for every single browser.